# I can't rotate my portrait app for a single screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, screen-rotation

[image]

This is some part of my storyboard, and I tried but I couldn't handle it.

What I tried in navigationController, and it didn't work. Have you any suggestions?

```
override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
    if self.topViewController != nil{
        return self.topViewController!.shouldAutorotate
    }else{
        return  super.shouldAutorotate
    }
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if self.topViewController != nil{
        return self.topViewController!.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }else{
        return  super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation{
    if self.topViewController != nil{
        return self.topViewController!.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    }else{
        return  super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    }
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return self.topViewController!.preferredStatusBarStyle
}
```

Comment: above code must be used in view controller

Comment: @Vinodh I tried in directly in ViewController but i threw an error, 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [EZPlayer.EZPlayerFullScreenViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Answer (score 0):

You can add this application life cycle method **supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor** into your app delegate class to support various orientation as per your requirement.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    if self.window?.rootViewController != nil {

        if self.window!.rootViewController! is UITabBarController {

            if self.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.last is UINavigationController {

                if self.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.last?.childViewControllers.last is YourViewController {
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all;
                } else {
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait;
                }

            } else {
                if self.window!.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.last is YourViewController {
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all;
                } else {
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait;
                }
            }                       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GreatCornholio Did you find my solution helpful to you?

Comment: nope sir, didn't work and crashed :/ 
Crash: 
Bailing on multiple uncaught exceptions: Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and `[EZPlayer.EZPlayerFloatContainerRootViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES
2018-02-18 15:07:34.823482+0300 DeMarke[1070:1109572] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [EZPlayer.EZPlayerFloatContainerRootViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'`

Comment: My ViewController contains only this code for rotation;

`override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
        return true
    }`